# OOP design issue - 'postulantet' object has no attribute 'tabla_postulante'

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter

I have a problem using tkinter and object-oriented programming.
I have 3 functions:

1. First I have the `v2()` function which is a function that allows to open a second window through a button and show the data saved in the database
2. My second function is `agregar_postulantes()`. This function saves the data in the database.
3. My third function is the one that saves the data of `agregar_postulantes()` and send it to the `v2()` function.

I want to emphasize that all the functions are in the same class and are declared outside the `__init__()`.

A short version of the code:

```
def v2(self):
    self.tabla_postulante=ttk.Treeview(tablaBD,columns=("Name","last name","id")
    self.tabla_postulante.heading("Name",text="Name")
    self.tabla_postulante.heading("last name",text="last name")
    self.tabla_postulante.heading("id",text="id")

    self.tabla_postulante['show']='headings'
    self.tabla_postulante.column("Name",width=100)
    self.tabla_postulante.column("last name",width=100)
    self.tabla_postulante.column("id",width=100)
    self.fetch_all()
    self.tabla_postulante.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=1)

def agregar_postulantes(self):
    con = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root",password="", database="postulantebd")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("insert into postulantes values(%s, %s, %s)",(
            self.name_var.get(),
            self.lastname_var.get(),
            self.id_var.get(),
            ))
    con.commit()
    self.fetch_all()
    con.close()

def fetch_all(self):
    con = pymysql.connect(host="localhost", user="root",password="", database="postulantebd")
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("select * from postulantes")
    rows=cur.fetchall()
    if len(rows)!=0:
        self.tabla_postulante.delete(*self.tabla_postulante.get_children())
        for row in rows:
            self.tabla_postulante.insert('',END,values=row)
        con.commit()
    con.close()
```

The error that appears is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dimitri\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\dimitri\Documents\Programas de Yolo\practicadeinterfazypoo\tkinter\interfaz_tesis_poo.py", line 273, in agregar_postulantes
    self.fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\dimitri\Documents\Programas de Yolo\practicadeinterfazypoo\tkinter\interfaz_tesis_poo.py", line 282, in fetch_all
    self.tabla_postulante.delete(*self.tabla_postulante.get_children())
AttributeError: 'postulante' object has no attribute 'tabla_postulante'
```

the error is because I am calling the v2 function after saving the data using the other two functions
How can I call the `v2` function afterwards and not show errors?

Comment: You need to have called `v2` which creates `tabla_postulante` before other methods that use it. Its not clear from this example whether that call was made.

Comment: Is the error message unclear? For example, do you understand what an `attribute` is?

Comment: I think that tabla_postulante is an attribute declared in v2.

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely that, as the `AttributeError` states, `self` has no `tabla_postulante` attribute. Since you create a `table_postulante` attribute on `self` in the `v2` function, I'd guess that you don't define `self.table_postulante` in the `__init__()` or you aren't calling `v2()` prior to calling `fetch_all()`.

Which *should* mean you have a couple options:

1. create some logic in `fetch_all()` that checks for the existence of `self.tabla_postulante` and only executes if that attribute is found. That could take the form of a `try`/`except` statement.
2. Alternatively, define the `self.tabla_postulante` attribute in your call to `__init__()` when the object is instantiated.

#### Update

A little more detail about implementing what I described above. I'm going to assume you aren't creating a `self.tabla_postulante` attribute on your class in the `__init__()`, since if you were you wouldn't be getting a `ValueError` when the function goes looking for it.

So this gives you a couple options. One would be to simply ensure that when you instantiate your class the `__init__()` creates a `self.table_postulante` attribute like so:

```py
class ClassName:
    def __init__(self):
        #create attribute here
        self.table_postulante = ttk.Treeview(tablaBD,columns=("Name", "last name","id")
        ...
```

Another option, if this doesn't make sense for the application you're developing, is to do some exception handling inside `fetch_all()`. For instance you could do something like:

```py
if len(rows)!=0:
    try:
        self.tabla_postulante.delete(*self.tabla_postulante.get_children())
        for row in rows:
            self.tabla_postulante.insert('',END,values=row)
        con.commit()
    except:
        #define some appropriate response to this attribute not existing here
```

Your use case will of course determine which approach makes the most sense. Hope this helps.

Comment: you're right, I call the 2nd and 3rd functions before using the first.
can you be a little more specific for the validation? I am a beginner

Comment: Absolutely! I'll put it in the answer so I can take advantage of Markdown to make it pretty.